# why my def function doesnt work with BMI term?

Tags: python

I'm calculating the BMI in spanish terms but I dont getting it. Why my code doesnt work?
Looks so frustrating

```
  >>> def IMC (estatura,peso):
    ...     IMC = estatura / peso
    ...     return "Tu índice de masa corporal es " + (IMC)
    ...
    >>> estatura = 185
    >>> peso = 74.60
    >>> IMC
    <function IMC at 0x0000019F36713E20>
    >>>
```

Comment: You need to call the function: `IMC(esatura, peso)`. You just have the shell print what the function is, hence the `<function IMC...>`.

Comment: Don't use a variable with the same name as the function. It's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IMC` is a function, which is exactly what you see in the ouput. If you want the function to execute you have to call it and pass parameters: `IMC(estatura, peso)`.

If you are familiar with functions in algebra, this is very similar. If you define `f(x) = x^2`, then you write `f(3)` to evaluate the function when `x` is given the value of `3`. We use a similar notation in python.

The assignments `estatura = 185` and `peso = 74.60` create new variables that have nothing to do with the ones with the same name inside the `IMC` function.

I suggest you read more about variables, functions, parameters, and scope to learn how this all works.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, Code-Apprentice, Robert and Barmar.
I'm learning myself Python, Java and JS, and Im very bad, I've been on this 1/2 months, every new word to me is a headache. I'm going to work a little more. Thanks guys

have a good day!
I GOT it but not for defining function, defining IMC = peso/estatura and after peso = x and estatura = y, and adding print(" some text " + str(IMC))

Comment: @Alexii07 There are a lot of new words to learn when learning programming. And it is probably even harder if English isn't your first language. Good luck to you! One small detail: when you do `IMC = peso/estatura`, you are defining a variable, not a function.